# How much does it cost to add a specialization to an A.I.?

Tags: character-advancement, planet-mercenary

Per the manual:

> **Skill Improvement**: Unlike most characters, your skills are only improved by spending Company Resources (see page 98). With
> permission from the group, the Company
> Resources may be reduced by 1 to grant you
> one rank in any skill of your choice. This may
> not be done during character creation but it
> may be done as often as you like thereafter
> (assuming the Company has the Resources to
> spend). Alternately, the company can spend
> Resources to increase the Company AI rating.
> (Prices for this are outlined on the AI Rating
> chart page 98). Raising the Company AI
> Rating grants you 10 additional skill points
> per rating increase.

Normally, buying a skill specialization costs 2 skill points during character creation, or can be picked in lieu of the 3 skill points you gain at the end of a successful mission.

So, the question is, can one buy specializations for an A.I. with company resources? If so, does it cost two? Three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I don't have a good answer for this one.

It's just something we forgot to answer. I'd suggest 3 w/ Company Resources. That keeps it aligned.